# CSS3 Support in wkhtmltopdf/rotativa

Tags: css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, rotativa

I need to create pdf by rotativa. And I need to show textarea into number of blank lines same as "rows" attribute, if the textarea doesn't have any content and need to show the content as well if there is any. and need to make the rest lines as blank.

I searched over net, and found a pure css3 way to make it done. And here is the textarea.

```
<textarea id="address" style="width:99%;border:none;font-size:19px;line-height:31px;width:100%;background-size: 100% 31px;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top , transparent, transparent 30px,#000000 0px);-moz-background-size: 100% 31px;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top , transparent, transparent 30px,#000000 0);-webkit-background-size: 100% 31px;" rows="5">test test</textarea>
```

It is showing in browser as expected, but while I am going to generate pdf from this html, the lines are not coming.
Please help, and please suggest if there is any other way to satisfy my requirement.

Thanks,
- Sovan

Comment: what's the URL of the page? have you tried running it through an online service like http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk to see if an optimized version of wkhtmltopdf works?

Comment: No, actually, there is no url. This is just an html content, which needs to be converted into pdf.

Comment: try passing it through http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/rawhtml then...

Comment: Just checked, it's too not showing as I expected.